# mV difference not detected by LM741 opamp comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I've made this comparator circuit, it has a changing current going through the photodiode and when lighting changes sufficiently it should trigger a 5V signal at the opamp output terminal.

When the photodiode is in low light conditions the non-inverting opamp input terminal has a voltage of 2mV. When I illuminate the photodiode I get a voltage of 20mV. I've adjusted R2 so that the inverting input terminal of the opamp is set to 10mV.

When I illuminate or darken the photo diode nothing changes to the output voltage of this opamp. Also nothing changes when I disconnect or switch the input terminals. It remains high (4.7V) at all times.

(I've measured all voltages directly to the opamp pins)

**Is there a design error? Or is the voltage difference too small?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjpzZ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What power supplies are connected to the op-amp?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use the 741.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522)

Comment: @ThePhoton 5V I understand that this is not enough, I will not use this opamp anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in observing the valid electrical parameter for Vin CM range (common-mode) on the datasheet.

The input transitors need this to bias  the NPN differential input amplifier.

You need a ground sensing comparator like the quad-LM339  (PNP inputs) or a negative Vee supply of at least 2V on the 741.

Comment: Indeed. Another option if one for some reason has to use the obsolete 741 and only has +5V and GND available is to change the operating condition of the photodiode so the opamp inputs are within its acceptable common-mode range. This can be done with only passives.

Comment: @pericynthion that passive bias solution to Vcc/2 would then demand passive tolerance errors much smaller than 22 Ohms / 22 kOhms or << 0.1% making it much less practical than an LM339 or require another pot making it too sensitive.

Comment: Doesn't need to be exactly vcc/2, you just make sure the reference is also based on the bias.

Comment: thanks, changed the opamp for one with better params